# How can I update values in multiple tables at once in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table (oc_product) with this columns:

| product_id | model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 42 |
| 2 | 43 |
| 3 | 44 |

I want to make `product_id = model`

```
UPDATE oc_product SET product_id = model WHERE model != product_id;
```

But I also have another table (oc_seo_url) with a `query` column and this column contains the IDs from the oc_product table, I need to change these values as well.

| query | keyword |
| --- | --- |
| `product_id=1` | test1 |
| `product_id=2` | test2 |
| `product_id=3` | test3 |

I figured out how to update one value at a time:

```
SET @idValue = 1;
SET @seoIdValue = CONCAT("product_id=", @idValue);

SELECT model INTO @modelValue FROM oc_product WHERE product_id LIKE @idValue;
SET @seoModelValue = CONCAT("product_id=", @modelValue);

UPDATE oc_product SET product_id = @modelValue WHERE model = @modelValue;
UPDATE oc_seo_url SET query = @seoModelValue WHERE query = @seoIdValue;
```

Result after this queries:

| product_id | model |
| --- | --- |
| 42 | 42 |
| 2 | 43 |
| 3 | 44 |

and

| query | keyword |
| --- | --- |
| `product_id=42` | test1 |
| `product_id=2` | test2 |
| `product_id=3` | test3 |

---

But how can I update everything at once? Do I need to use loops for this? I want to get:

| product_id | model |
| --- | --- |
| 42 | 42 |
| 43 | 43 |
| 44 | 44 |

and

| query | keyword |
| --- | --- |
| `product_id=42` | test1 |
| `product_id=43` | test2 |
| `product_id=44` | test3 |

---

I tried it with a while loop, but I can't figure out how it should work in MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN

SELECT product_id INTO @idValue FROM oc_product WHERE product_id != model;
SELECT model INTO @modelValue FROM oc_product WHERE product_id LIKE @idValue;

WHILE (@idValue != @modelValue) DO
SET @seoIdValue = CONCAT("product_id=", @idValue);
SET @seoModelValue = CONCAT("product_id=", @modelValue);
UPDATE oc_product SET product_id = @modelValue WHERE model = @modelValue;
UPDATE oc_seo_url SET query = @seoModelValue WHERE query = @seoIdValue;
END WHILE;

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need any dowhile() first you need to update the **oc_seo_url** table because this is the dependent table which we need to update the query column first. Then you can update the **oc_product** table

```
update oc_seo_url os
left join oc_product op on op.product_id =  cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(os.query,'=',-1) AS UNSIGNED)
set os.query = concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(os.query,'=',1),'=',cast(op.model as char) );

UPDATE oc_product SET product_id = model WHERE model != product_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but in **oc_seo_url** I also have another data (example: category_id=42, manufacturer_id=42) and after this request all this data is deleted. So I don't need to touch this data. How can I skip these rows?

Comment: @nashyvan I am not able to understand what you are trying to explain. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by having another data (example: category_id=42, manufacturer_id=42) and what is getting deleted ?

Comment: Sure. [image](https://i.ibb.co/WBbM5YM/SCR-20231112-sayp.png)

Comment: @nashyvan you just need to add where condition in the above query at the end 
where os.query like = '%product_id%'